# How to learn physics on my own

Tags: education, applied-physics

I am 14 year old I want to learn physics up to a level where I can invent stuff. I want to be an inventor so I need to learn Mechanical physics at the moment. I am comfortable with both mathematical approach and principle approach. Books I should use and how I should learn like what things to study before studying calculus. I mainly want someone to tell which thing to learn first and which to study later.

Comment: Useful link http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gadda001/goodtheorist/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you start learning physics by yourself?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33222/)